# Webstorm Mocha unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, webstorm

I'm using the latest Webstorm v7.0.2.  This version supports node js unit testing with Mocha out of the box.

With the recent addition of a test file, it has stopped running any of the tests.  The unhelpful error I'm getting is a 'Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly'.  The process finishes with an exit code 1, and there's nothing in my log files.

The peculiar thing is, if I comment out the code inside this new test file, all of my other tests complete successfully.  Thinking it is a problem with this specific file, I ran mocha from the cli only on this file.  My single test completes successfully.

The first time I added this test, its name was a duplicate with another test.  Thinking this was the problem, I changed the name but it hasn't helped.

The test file in question is a restify RESTful web service.  It is the second server that I'm testing.  If I comment out the first test file, the second test file that has never worked starts completing.  I've thought that maybe the servers are trying to bind to the same port, so I specified the port manually, but that hasn't fixed it either.

My test files look like the following.

```
var SERVER;
var PORT;
var CLIENT;

describe('serviceA', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    SERVER = serviceA.createServer();
    SERVER.should.exist;

    SERVER.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', function() {
      PORT = SERVER.address().port;

      CLIENT = clients.createServiceAClient({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + PORT
      });
      CLIENT.should.exist;

      process.nextTick(done);
    });

  });

[...]

});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `process.nextTick()`?

Comment: I'm using mcavage's tests as templates for my own.  He also calls it in https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/blob/master/test/client.test.js.  Since I'm connecting to mongoose on the server, I figure a delay can't hurt.

Comment: His test files are written for `node-unit`, not `mocha`. Calling `done()` should suffice and may solve your issue.

Comment: see [WEB-10184](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10184) - may be related